# UnReachableBrowserException in Chome with Selenium Webdriver

Tags: selenium

i am getting UnhandledBrowserException when trying the below code in chrome:

public class myClass {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // declaration and instantiation of objects/variables

    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C://Program Files (x86)//Google//Chrome//Application//chrome.exe");
    WebDriver driver= new ChromeDriver();


    String baseURL = "http://newtours.demoaut.com";
    String expectedTitle = "Welcome: Mercury Tours";
    String actualTitle = "";

    // launch Firefox and direct it to the Base URL
    driver.get(baseURL);
    // get the actual value of the title
    actualTitle = driver.getTitle();

    /*
     * compare the actual title of the page witht the expected one and print
     * the result as "Passed" or "Failed"
     */
    if (actualTitle.contentEquals(expectedTitle)){
        System.out.println("Test Passed!");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Test Failed");
    }

    //close Firefox
    driver.close();

    // exit the program explicitly
    System.exit(0);
}
```

It is launching a new session in chrome but then throwing the exception. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UnreachableBrowserException trying to launch in Selenium Webdriver using IEDriver](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17066424/unreachablebrowserexception-trying-to-launch-in-selenium-webdriver-using-iedrive)

Comment: Posting exception is always nice.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are hitting program executable instead of driver.

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/path/to/chromedriver");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
```

It should be path to chrome driver not the chrome browser executable.
You can take a look at https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/getting-started