# Running testng.xml using batch file from command line or Jenkins

Tags: xml, batch-file, jenkins, testng

While running testng.xml via batch file or command line getting error.
Error: Could not find or load main class org.testng.TestNG.
Batch file details mentioned below:

---

```
set projectLocation=C:\GitRapo\MyProject
cd C:\GitRapo\MyProject
set classpath=C:\GitRapo\MyProject\bin;C:\GitRapo\MyProject\lib\*
java org.testng.TestNG C:\GitRapo\MyProject\testng.xml
pause
```

---

Getting same error when trying to run through Jenkins. PFA screenshot for more details.
[image]

Comment: Do you run it normally using IntelliJ?

Comment: how are you importing the libs?

Comment: I am adding external dependencies to my Project using Build path section in eclipse. My project is in eclipse all jars are added to it.

Comment: @ Grzegorz Górkiewicz normally run it in Eclipse as testNG, thats working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TestNG is not in your classpath.
Run `java` command with the `-cp` option to add TestNG to your classpath.
I see you already have the `classpath` variable set, so just use it:

```
java -cp %classpath% org.testng.TestNG %ProjectPath%\testng.xml
```

If there is a naming convention for the language you are using, go for it.

By the way, I normally use Maven to figure out classpaths etc.
Normally `mvn clean install` is enough.

Comment: Thanks @Grzegorz Górkiewicz was able to run. One problem is still there, its working fine with cmd but when run the same batch through jenkins then my test cases are getting skipped. Can you help me out with this? PFA screenshot for error details.

Comment: C:\GitRapo\MyProject>testNGBatchFile.bat
C:\GitRapo\MyProject>set projectLocation=C:\GitRapo\MyProject 
C:\GitRapo\MyProject>cd C:\GitRapo\MyProject 
C:\GitRapo\MyProject>set classpath=C:\GitRapo\MyProject\bin;C:\GitRapo\MyProject\lib\* 
C:\GitRapo\MyProject>java -cp C:\GitRapo\MyProject\bin;C:\GitRapo\MyProject\lib\* org.testng.TestNG C:\GitRapo\MyProject\testng.xml

Comment: Reason for failure is FAILED CONFIGURATION: @BeforeClass setUp("http://127.0.0.1:4727/wd/hub")
org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: 
Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure.

Comment: Blind guess: do not close your driver in `@AfterClass`. This is another question. Please tell us more in another question.

Comment: So the point is that my code has a logic to interact with the command prompt. It will open cmd and go to a particular directory and then start a batch file which has the code to start appium server at a specific port.

Comment: [Another possible reason for this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21882421/4280359). You should ask another question (more users will see).

Comment: no this might not be the issue as I am not using any binaries. My code is using Android driver to run the test on a real device. May be you're right I need to put up a new question. By the way thanks for the help :)

Comment: is it possible to interact with windows UI (cmd prompt) using Jenkins. That might be an issue. Not sure though.

Comment: Jenkins offers build steps like "Execute shell" that might be helpful.